# Get text reviews from goodreads using the API

Tags: python, api

I trying to extract the reviews  from goodreads using the API.

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/goodreads-ratings-api/
And the API documentation:
https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#review.show

With this url:

```
https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json?key={apikey}&isbns=9789082425406
```

I get the following information:

```
{"books":[{"id":28349851,"isbn":"9082425408","isbn13":"9789082425406","ratings_count":16,"reviews_count":2481,"text_reviews_count":5,"work_ratings_count":16,"work_reviews_count":2482,"work_text_reviews_count":5,"average_rating":"4.06"}]}
```

But if I try to use the method "show" instead od "review_counts"

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show.json?key={apikey}&isbns=9789082425406

I get this error:
"Could not find this book."

Comment: I think you want `show_by_isbn` rather than `show` which expects to receive a book id.

Comment: @BillBell It says page not found

Answer (score 3):

According to the Goodreads API docs, the [`/book/show`](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.show) endpoint takes an internal book ID as parameter.

To query by ISBN, hit the [`/book/isbn`](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.show_by_isbn) (click for docs) endpoint instead.

In the description of the endpoint, this example is provided:

```
GET https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/0441172717
```

Comment: like this: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show_by_isbn.json?key={apikey}&isbns=9789082425406  ? is not working

Comment: No. I edited the question above to add an example URL. Check the documentation, I'm just reading it to you =)